# Node-red admin page not loading

Tags: vps, node-red

I've noticed today that I can't load the node-red admin page, I've checked the 1880 port status and it's still open and it's even show that node-red as a listener on 1880.

Knowing that I'm working on Ubuntu ( VPS ) does anyone know how I can solve this problem? or how I can restart node-red ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can stop and start the service via `node-red-stop` / `node-red-start`. How are you trying to load the page? What URL are you using? What's the setup?

Comment: If I use `node-red-stop` I get `node-red-stop: command not found`. 
 and as always this is the url I use : myserver.com:1880/admin ( it worked perfectly some hours ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/node-red-admin#target-and-login)

> To remotely administer a Node-RED instance, the tool must first be pointed at the Node-RED instance you want it to access. By default, it assumes http://localhost:1880. To change that, use the target command:
>
> `node-red-admin target http://node-red.example.com/admin`

Comment: I've done this before, and I add authentification page, the problem is now I can't even access to the :1880/admin page nor the :1880. I believe restarting it will solve the problem, but I couldn't figure out how, do you have any idea how I can find and kill PID of node-red? NB: everything worked fine hours ago even with /admin.

Comment: @kml2019 strange, well assuming you aren't running anything else Node related, you could just run `ps aux | grep node` to find the PID, it'll be the process running a script called `red.js`, and then `sudo kill <pid>`....the concern I'd have is how do start it back up if you don't have `node-red-*` services? Are you manually starting it?

Comment: this is what I get from running `ps aux | grep node` :   `innovat+  1649 98.9  9.2 750444 185780 ?       Rsl  15:16  72:18 node-red
root      3423  0.0  0.0  12944   940 pts/0    S+   16:29   0:00 grep --color=auto node` how can I find the PID please? I used to run`node-red` to start it.
`

Comment: @kml2019 ah ok, in that case the PID here is 3423

Comment: Thanks, just done it, and didn't solve anything...there's anyway that I can delete all the flows I made?

Comment: @kml2019 why if Node-RED was running fine would you suspect a problem with the flows? Are you able to remote into the target machine and access it via `localhost`?

Comment: I didn't understand, I've access to the machine via SSH and WINsCP

Comment: I've just solved it by deleting all my flows manualy using ` cd /home/mydict/.node-red

rm flows.json`, I believe someone of my colleague did  some changes in the flows, but what I can't understand why does changing the flows can cause problems in the admin page...hopefuly I had a copy of  my work in a json file.